# showing the power series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n^2}$ is holomorphic in the open unit disk but not closed

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, uniform-convergence

I need to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n^2}$ is continuous in the closed unit disk and holomorphic in the open unit disk but not holomorphic in the the closed disk.

I showed that the series is convergent absolutely and uniformly on compact subsets of the closed unit disk (by the M-test), then the series is holomorphic (and so continuous ) but still not sure how to prove that it is continuous on the boundary not holomorphic on the boundary.

Comment: What's the derivative of your power series? In particular, what happens to the derivative when $z = 1$?

Comment: @Geoff, it is harmonic series. so divergent. I see!   So, we apply M-test on the open disk or the closed disk?

Comment: @Geoff, and how do we prove the continuity of $f$ at the boundary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The series converges uniformly on the closed unit disk, by the $M$-test, so it is continuous there.  To be holomorphic at a point, a function must be differentiable in a neighborhood of the point.  If it is holomorphic on the closed disk, then for every $z$ with $|z|=1$ there is an open disk centered at $z$ on which the function is holomorphic.  Since the boundary is compact, finitely many such disks cover the boundary, so the series is holomorphic is some disk $|z|<r$ where $r>1$.  This is absurd, since the radius of convergence is $1$.

Actually, we know by [Pringsheim's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vivanti%E2%80%93Pringsheim_theorem) that the the function cannot be holomorphic in a neighborhood of $1$.

Answer (score 1):

This is the di-logarithm function.   It has radius of convergence  $1$, by Cauchy-Hadamard.  It converges absolutely on the boundary,  by comparison with $\sum_{n\ge0}1/n^2$.

It's derivative is $g (z)/z $, where $g (z)=-\ln (1-z) $.  $g (z)=\sum_{n\ge0}z^n/n $ doesn't converge at $z=1$.  Thus it is not holomorphic on the closed disk.

Comment: but how can we show the continuity on the boundary?

Comment: we can't.  It has a jump discontinuity across the cut.